# Graphic editor opensource project example on c++ underlying composite pattern

Tags: c++, oop, open-source, design-patterns

Can you tell me where I can see a some opensource project (only project on C++ language), which is simple graphic editor, сontaining following primitive (for example): an ellipse, a rectangle, a line. And desirable, that to be able to group this primitive in one primitive (for example, Word Grouping -> Group).
Composite pattern use is desirable in this project. I want to see how to organize classes, but more serious for me is to see how organize grouping operation.

I searched for it on codeproject.com codeproject.com, codeplex.com, but not found this.

I have already some source http://pastebin.com/xe4JF5PW

But in my opinion, this code is dirty and ugly. Therefore, I want to see some opensource project for example. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GoF book **"Design Patterns : Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software"**, there is a Case-Study that shows how to employ the patterns. They namely describe the way to use the Composite design pattern for graphical purpose. (Using Glyphs, a glyphs being a graphical component).

They base their case-study on a real text/graphical editor called **Lexi**.

Unluckily for you, the code is in DELPHI, not C++. But the code is here: [LEXI](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/design_patterns/the_lexi_editor/the_lexi_editor.html).

However, it is explained among the thourough explanations of the Gang of Four book. You should take a look at the book if the site explanations aren't clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know Pascal language. And I have some experience in developing any projects in Delphi.

Comment: You're welcome. The composite pattern has helped me in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape might be what your searching for, it is a popular open source vector graphics editor written (mostly) in c++.

https://code.edge.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev